# error in long number addition using character array

Tags: c

The code written below is working out quite fine but gives out only one error which I cannot find out why. When we add numbers like `99+1` or `999+1` it prints only the zeroes but not one. If you point out the error in the code and correct it i would rather be thankful for your help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num1[255], num2[255], sum[255];
    char s1[255], s2[255];
    int l1, l2,h;

    printf("Enter Number1:");
    scanf("%s", &s1);
    printf("Enter Number2:");
    scanf("%s", &s2);


    for (l1 = 0; s1[l1] != '\0'; l1++)
        num1[l1] = s1[l1] - 48;

    for (l2 = 0; s2[l2] != '\0'; l2++)
        num2[l2] = s2[l2] - 48;

    int carry = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int i = l1 - 1;
    int j = l2 - 1;

    for (; i >= 0 && j >= 0; i--, j--, k++)
    {
        sum[k] = (num1[i] + num2[j] + carry) % 10;
        carry = (num1[i] + num2[j] + carry) / 10;
    }

    if(l1==0 && carry==1)
    {
        sum[k++]=1;
    }
    else if (l1 > l2)
    {
        while (i >= 0)
        {
            sum[k++] = (num1[i--] + carry)%10 ;
            carry = (num1[i]+carry)/10;
        }
        if(i==0&&carry==1)
        {
            sum[k++]=carry;
        }
    }
    else if(l1<l2)
    {
        while (j >= 0)
        {
            sum[k++] = (num2[j--] + carry)%10 ;
            carry = (num2[j]+carry)/10;
        }
        if(j==0&&carry==1)
        {
            sum[k++]=carry;
        }
    }

    printf("Result:");

    for (k--; k>= 0; k--)
        printf("%d", sum[k]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you done anything to debug your program? Namely use a debugger and/or add debug print statements to trace the execution of your program?

Comment: Please properly indent your code before posting it.

Comment: A few thing I've noticed, 1)`num1[i--]` in your while loops and then you use `i` again `num1[i]` after the value of `i` has changed. it is better to just use `i` as an index then decrements it at the end of the loop. 2)`if(i==0&&carry==1)` this will not work since in your while loop `i` can go up to 0 and can become -1 when the loop terminates. You probably meant `if(i<0&&carry==1)`

Comment: `scanf("%s", &s1);` --> `scanf("%s", s1);` or `scanf("%s", &s1[0]);`

Comment: @kaylum as i am pretty new to coding i have no idea regarding debuggin. i would be glad if you do that for me.

Comment: Really?? You want others to debug for you instead of learning to debug yourself? And what happens when you hit the next problem? Just going to post each problem on Stackoverflow as it occurs?

Comment: @kaylum thanks bro your advice was fruitful. I learnt debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write the carry counter, and then read it. You code only needed a minor adjustment for the carry, then it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num1[255], num2[255], sum[255];
    char s1[255], s2[255];
    int l1, l2;

    printf("Enter Number1:");
    scanf("%s", s1);
    printf("Enter Number2:");
    scanf("%s", s2);    

    for (l1 = 0; s1[l1] != '\0'; l1++)
        num1[l1] = s1[l1] - '0';

    for (l2 = 0; s2[l2] != '\0'; l2++)
        num2[l2] = s2[l2] - '0';

    int carry = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int i = l1 - 1;
    int j = l2 - 1;
    for (; i >= 0 && j >= 0; i--, j--, k++) {
        sum[k] = (num1[i] + num2[j] + carry) % 10;
        carry = (num1[i] + num2[j] + carry) / 10;
    }
    if (l1 > l2) {


        while (i >= 0) {
            sum[k++] = (num1[i] + carry) % 10;
            carry = (num1[i--] + carry) / 10;
        }

        if (sum[k - 1] != carry)
            sum[k++] = carry;

    } else if (l1 < l2) {
        while (j >= 0) {
            sum[k++] = (num2[j] + carry) % 10;
            carry = (num2[j--] + carry) / 10;
        }
        if (sum[k - 1] != carry)
            sum[k++] = carry;
    } else {
        if (carry > 0)
            sum[k++] = carry;
    }


    printf("Result:");
    for (k--; k >= 0; k--)
        printf("%d", sum[k]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Test**

```
Enter Number1:99
Enter Number2:1
Result:100
```

**Test 2**

```
Enter Number1:9999999999999999999999999999999999
Enter Number2:1
Result:10000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 2):

1. In the while loop (i>=0), you are decrementing the index `i` in the sum step. You are using this index again in the carry step below. You should decerement it at the next carry step.
2. The `if` condition after that, is `if(i==0&&carry==1)` `i` will be always -1 at the end of the loop. So the conditionfor `i==0` can be removed.

The fixed code is below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  int num1[255], num2[255], sum[255];
  char s1[255], s2[255];
  int l1, l2,h;

  printf("Enter Number1:");
  scanf("%s", s1);
  printf("Enter Number2:");
  scanf("%s", s2);


  for (l1 = 0; s1[l1] != '\0'; l1++)
    num1[l1] = s1[l1] - 48;

  for (l2 = 0; s2[l2] != '\0'; l2++)
    num2[l2] = s2[l2] - 48;

  int carry = 0;
  int k = 0;
  int i = l1 - 1;
  int j = l2 - 1;
  for (; i >= 0 && j >= 0; i--, j--, k++) {
    sum[k] = (num1[i] + num2[j] + carry) % 10;
    carry = (num1[i] + num2[j] + carry) / 10;
  }
  if(l1==0&&carry==1)
  {
    sum[k++]=1;
  }
  else if (l1 > l2) {

    while (i >= 0) {
      sum[k++] = (num1[i] + carry)%10 ;
      carry = (num1[i--]+carry)/10;
    }
    if(carry==1)
    {
      sum[k++]=carry;
    }
  } else if(l1<l2) {
    while (j >= 0) {
      sum[k++] = (num2[j] + carry)%10 ;
      carry = (num2[j--]+carry)/10;
    }
    if(carry==1)
    {
      sum[k++]=carry;

    }
  }

  printf("Result:");
  for (k--; k>= 0; k--)
    printf("%d", sum[k]);

  return 0;
}
```

**Test1**

```
Enter Number1:99
Enter Number2:2
Result:101
```

**Test2**

```
Enter Number1:22
Enter Number2:99998
Result:100020
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I think this should help you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int num1[255], num2[255], sum[255];
char s1[255], s2[255];
int l1, l2,h;

printf("Enter Number1:");
scanf("%s", &s1);
printf("Enter Number2:");
scanf("%s", &s2);

for (l1 = 0; s1[l1] != '\0'; l1++)
    num1[l1] = s1[l1] - '0';

for (l2 = 0; s2[l2] != '\0'; l2++)
    num2[l2] = s2[l2] - '0';

int carry = 0;
int k = 0;
int i = l1 - 1;
int j = l2 - 1;

for (; i >= 0 && j >= 0; i--, j--, k++)
{
    sum[k] = (num1[i] + num2[j] + carry) % 10;
    carry = (num1[i] + num2[j] + carry) / 10;
}

//if num2 has more digits than num1

if(i==-1 && j>=0)
{  
      while(j>=0)
      {
          sum[k++]=(num2[j]+carry)%10;
          carry=(num2[j]+carry)/10;
          j--;
      }
}

//if num1 has more digits than num2

if(i>=0 && j==-1)
{  
      while(i>=0)
      {
          sum[k++]=(num1[i]+carry)%10;
          carry=(num1[i]+carry)/10;
          i--;
      }
}
 // both has reached to their last digits position and suppose the carry is still left
 if(i==-1 && j==-1)
 { 
    if(carry>0)
      sum[k++]=carry;
 }

printf("Result:");

for (k=k-1; k>= 0; k--)
    printf("%d", sum[k]);

return 0;
}
```